# select fields in mysql problem

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got stuck on selecting fields from a table using SQL and PHP.

I have a table named `invitations` with those fields:

- senderid
- receiverid1
- receiverid2
- ...
- receiverid10

I have different rows with the same `senderid` and want to select the `receiverid`  corresponding to it.

Some `receiversid` may be null so I filter only non null value.

Here is my code:

```
$d1 = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser ,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $d1);

/* fetching receivers */
$q1 = mysql_query("select receiverid1,receiverid2,receiverid3,receiverid4,
        receiverid5,receiverid6,receiverid7,receiverid8,receiverid9,receiverid10  
        from invitations 
        where senderid = '528495538' ", $d1);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q1))
{ 
    $totalreceivers = count(array_filter($row));
    $receivers[] = array_filter($row);

}
echo '<br>';    
echo "the receivers";
echo '<br>';
print_r($receivers);
echo '<br>';
echo $totalreceivers;
```

With the above sender id, on the table I have 2 rows but when I execute the code I get only one:

the receivers `Array ( [0] => 1743650643 [receiverid1] => 1743650643 ) 2`

Any kind of help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `$recievers` into an array, and `$totalreceivers` into an int starting at 0, and declare them before the loop. You are reassigning them on each loop instead of adding to them:

```
$totalreceivers = 0;
$receivers = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q1)) {
  $filtered = array_filter($row);
  $totalreceivers += count($filtered);
  $receivers[] = $filtered;
}
```

Note that it is more efficient to call `array_filter()` once and assign it to a variable than it is to call it twice for each operation. Also, especially for the operation above, use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`.

**EDIT** See if this is more like what you want (slightly fixed)...

```
$receivers = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q1)) {
  foreach (array_filter($row) as $item) {
    $receivers[] = $item;
  }
}
$totalreceivers = count($receivers);
```

Comment: tanks for the response i copied your code . and got 2 receiversid as in the table . but got an array and every element inside is another array !!!! i want only one array . how can i do it ?

Comment: What is the data in each column? Is any of it likely to be reapeated?

Comment: there are two rows both have a field name senderid and is the same '528495538'. then there are receiverid1 , receiverid2 etc ..they are not repeated the receiversid

Comment: DaveRandom you are a star thanks , that did exactly the trick and got an array with 1 dimension array with the two ids . every day learning something new . cheers

Comment: No probs. Remember that as a general rule you should always use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` over `mysql_fetch_array()`, in the above code the latter would have resulted in every item being in the array twice...

Answer (score 0):

update it like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q1))
{ 
$totalreceivers += count(array_filter($row));
$receivers[] = array_filter($row);

}
echo '<br>';    
echo "the receivers";
echo '<br>';
print_r($receivers);
```

Comment: Better to do an implicit array push like `$receivers[]` than to worry about the `$i` counter

Comment: ... and I would imagine the OP wants `$totalreceivers` to be a running total, rather than the count of the last iteration of the `while`...

Comment: thank you mithunsatheesh , i tried your code and got the same as DaveRandom ==> an array with every element like another array !!

Comment: @user888300:it will be a 2d array.. then how you want the output..?

Comment: @user888300:if its not a 2d array, then how will you access the receiverid1 of separate rows?

Comment: i acces it doing a loop : for ($i = 0; $i < $totalreceivers; $i++) { echo "<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/$receivers[$i]/picture' width='40' style='float:left;margin-right:10px;border:1px solid #ccc;'/>";
}

Answer (score 0):

Your table definition is obviously wrong.

You should move receiverids into separate table